# Problems with Google Maps V2

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-maps-v2

I'm trying to make an application with maps, following the tutorial Google demonstrated in this [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=awX5T-EwLPc). The problem is that when i run it the error and closes and will not appear that error. But debugging the code I saw that the element in the XML fragment is the problem, since the retreat when the app runs, but no map, when I place does not open.

I really do not know what to do.

PS: My code is identical to the tutorial which can be viewed through this [link](http://www.cs.sfu.ca/CourseCentral/276/bfraser/androidExampleCode/AndroidGoogleMapsAPIDemo.zip).

Comment: where are u debuging ur code? virtual device or real device?

Comment: Just post the code plus the full stack trace

Comment: Do you want SO members to debug your demo application for you. Provide StackTrace, `the error in XML` and the device specifications on which you were testing it.

Comment: Guys User is on Sleeping Mode. so solve his issue in dreams!

Comment: in which you provided the link in that there is no code..

Answer (score 0):

In ur project u have import `wrong library` import `google-play-services_lib` into ur `same workspace` as a `library project` where `DemoGoogleMapsV2` project is.Then add that `library project` in `DemoGoogleMapsV2`

Path of `google-play-services_lib`

**SDK--->extras--->google--->
google_play_services--->libproject----->google-play-services-lib**

---

*in manfest make some changes*

```
android:minSdkVersion="11"
```

to

```
android:minSdkVersion="12"
```

*add this meta-data tag* in **application tag** u have to specify which google play service version u r using

```
<meta-data
      android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
      android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

Make sure u have generated ur own `API-Key` for ur project using `ur_machine's_SHA-1_fingerprint;package name` otherwise `Map will not displayed`

### for more info [GO Through This](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#getting_the_google_maps_android_api_v2)

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#getting_the_google_maps_android_api_v2